# Caps lock indicator for kubuntu 14.04

Tags: capslock

I'm looking for a software-based caps lock indicator for Kubuntu 14.04. I found one from 2010 at kde-apps, but installing it was a disaster. It deleted practically all of my system software in order to get the version it wanted.  I found another, more recent one, but it only works for Unity.

Any hope?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the Unity version, but you could give it a try.

Open Terminal and type:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsbarnes/indicator-keylock`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install indicator-keylock indicator-keylock-*`

[image]